# add images to placemakrs google maps

Tags: google-maps

I thought this would be simple enough but i cant seem to find a solution to this. All the examples online talk about "editing html" but this option is not there in the maps...at least i cant see it. All i want to do is add a image to the custom place mark I have created. I have made the map public

URL: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=z7IEPC0nBH4A.kVBxNdxzStY8

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two bugs in your html code:

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4olxpkce50nijq6/ttNsJsNx5l/IMG_6080.JPG?m />
```

**First**, there are missing ending Quotation Mark:

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4olxpkce50nijq6/ttNsJsNx5l/IMG_6080.JPG?m" />
```

**Second**, you are linking to invalid dropbox image url,

instead of linking "image", you linked to "dropbox page" with this image

try this:

```
<img src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/0/AACDK3--td1dHfzvjPpZJV7nOHG4TetLvnZcq57l0dPI-g/12/11970178/jpeg/1024x768/3/1367881200/0/2/IMG_6080.JPG/Ipzuc65vlNu4q5l1IRF6ByweEjvI54jmqjRGonaT55Y%2CNbkC0I3psIX50JxgE7E9ooD5ZE9BHKQ13r62AelzYNo" />
```